# Java client program calling a .NET 3.5 web service

Tags: .net, web-services, .net-3.5, tomcat

i have written a simple java stand-alone program that calls a .net 1.0 web service. no problem. if i take that same program structure and call a .net 3.5 web service, the java program fails. for whatever reason, the parameters passed to the 3.5 service are NEVER received.

so can someone point the way to an example or tutorial where i can call a .net 3.5 web service from a java stand-alone application (without using glassfish, tomcat, etc). i didn't have to install a server (tomcat) when i called the 1.0 service and so i am assumming that you can do the same when calling a 3.5 service.

i've been spending numerous days researching this topic and i'm getting desperate. thank you.

ac

p.s. i don't want code fragments.....i need a full blown tutorial from top to bottom.

Comment: I would first verify the web service using soapUI

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be anything special you need to do. Just use any tutorial for a Java client calling any document/literal web service.

You should keep in mind that .NET 1.0 was a long time ago, and had bugs that have been fixed. It's possible that you were depending on those bugs, but didn't know you were.

Comment: .NET can publish webservices via MTOM which requires some something like metro.

Comment: Seriously? Java doesn't have native MTOM support?

Comment: It depends which library you're using.

Comment: It has to do with the specifics of WCF which I'm not all that familiar with. https://metro.dev.java.net/guide/How_Metro_Relates_to__NET_Windows_Communication_Foundation__WCF_.html has a little more info.

Comment: @Steve: the specifics of WCF or the specifics of WS-Security? The theory is that WCF implements WS-Security, and so should be compatible. If there are incompatiblities, it would be a good thing to know!

Comment: @John so WCF is supposed to implement  WS-Addressing, WS-ReliableMessaging and WS-Security.  There might be potential for ambiguity and corner cases that could cause incompatibilities especially where the standards interact. Standards can be a funny thing.  Look at how bad the situation is with web browsers. It looks like the big companies are trying to make sure that isn't happening with the open communications standards which is a good thing.

Comment: @Steve: yes, it's meant to support all that, and if you hit any such "corner cases", then please report them so they can be fixed!

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to have a look at  [Metro](https://metro.dev.java.net/guide/).

A more specific example is probably the [from-wsdl example found here.](https://metro.dev.java.net/getting-started/basic.html)